# Bluetooth - Receive data from multiple device in same time on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to receive data from multiple device in same time, i'm using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() and the SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB to connect to non-android devices.

So i'm running 3 instance of ConnectedThread, i'm able to write to all device, but i can't receive from 2 device at same time.

Example : i'm connecting to 2 Pc using HyperTerminal, if i send a txt file on both at the same time, i will receive only one on my android device, the other one is ignored.

I'm looking this library : http://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/ seems i have to run a server on my android phone.

How can I achieve this?

Best regards.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
    // member streams are final
    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

/* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

/* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

}

Comment: see the BluetoothChat example distributed with the Android SDKs, it is a good example https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java. You may want to run in a server mode and  do listen on multiple connections instead of client mode trying to connect to multiple devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm connecting to bluetooth device which can't connect my phone (like printer ect...) . I don't have the choice, i have to create a connection to each device. And if i connect to my pc, i get some connection problem on this one.